# QGIS python QgsApplication.pluginPath() return wrong path in Debian

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

plugin_path = QgsApplication.pluginPath()  return wrong path in Debian

/usr/lib/qgis/plugins

corect path is : /home/web/.qgis2/python/plugins/

in windows the returned path it's ok.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mis understand what `QgsApplication.pluginPath` is meant to return.  The path it returns is the plugins for the application itself, not the user plugins.

Application plugins include the data providers, C++ core plugins, etc

Comment: Meanwhile I understand, but thanks for the reply . Any function for user pluginpath, or i must deal with PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score -1):

os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**), '')